# Meteor 1.2.1 MongoDB Invalid Modifier $currentDate

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I recently updated to Meteor 1.2.1 and deployed my project to the meteor development servers {app}.meteor.com However, upon doing so I started noticing errors with the $currentDate modifier in my mongo update statements.

This was working before the update and actually works locally. However, seems to be broken on the deployment. Thoughts on this?

The code:

```
Members.update({burnId: burnId, "isViewing": { $eq : false}}, { $inc: { "numUnreadMessages": 1}, $currentDate: {updatedAt: true}}, {multi: true});
```

**UPDATE**: I actually ran `meteor mongo {app}.meteor.com` and tried to run a simple update command `db.collection.update({_id: "1234"}, {$currentDate: {updatedAt: true}})` and it worked on the local copy, but not on the deployed version.

I'm assuming that the deployment servers (free) for meteor are having trouble running Meteor 1.2. Is there a way to resolve this? I also assume this will be fixed with Galaxy, but alas that's not available to the general public yet.

The logs:

```
[Sun Sep 27 2015 15:56:51 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO Exception while invoking method 'sendMessage' MongoError: Invalid modifier specified $currentDate
at Object.Future.wait (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.5.13/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1)
at [object Object].MongoConnection.(anonymous function) (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:736:1)
at [object Object].mongoConnectionProto.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:2923:1)
at OptimizedApply (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:271:1)
at Object.ret.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:2881:1)
at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/mongo/collection.js:586:1)
at [object Object].Meteor.methods.sendMessage (server/Methods.js:124:1)
at [object Object].methodMap.(anonymous function) (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:2554:1)
at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1692:12)
- - - - -
at Object.toError (/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:114:11)
at /meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:636:22
at Server.Base._callHandler (/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:453:41)
at /meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:488:18
at [object Object].MongoReply.parseBody
(/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:446:20)
at [object Object].emit (events.js:95:17)
at [object Object].<anonymous>
(/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:207:13)
at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:440:22)
[Sun Sep 27 2015 15:56:54 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO Exception while invoking method 'sendMessage' MongoError: Invalid modifier specified $currentDate
at Object.Future.wait (/meteor/dev_bundles/0.5.13/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1)
at [object Object].MongoConnection.(anonymous function) (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:736:1)
at [object Object].mongoConnectionProto.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:2923:1)
at OptimizedApply (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:271:1)
at Object.ret.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:2881:1)
at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/mongo/collection.js:586:1)
at [object Object].Meteor.methods.sendMessage (server/Methods.js:124:1)
at [object Object].methodMap.(anonymous function) (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:2554:1)
at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1692:12)
- - - - -
at Object.toError (/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:114:11)
at /meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:636:22
at Server.Base._callHandler (/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:453:41)
at /meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:488:18
at [object Object].MongoReply.parseBody
(/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:446:20)
at [object Object].emit (events.js:95:17)
at [object Object].<anonymous>
(/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:207:13)
at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/951f3aa3-e3e5-e5bf-afc8-323fba10ef52/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:440:22)
```

Comment: The free service probably uses an older version of mongo.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I figured. Do you have any recommendations. Perhaps Modulus? I hear that have a simple deployment process for meteor applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with Meteor's free version. Using an updated version of mongo does the trick.